# Building a jmeter sampler using spring dependencies

Tags: java, spring, jmeter

I'm very much new with JMeter and I'm trying to reuse my testing library to perform my loading tests.

I've started with a small project. There I have a class which implements `org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSamplerClient`, I've compiled it and copied the jar into the `.\lib\ext` folder of jmeter.

**Result**: I could see my sampler and run it perfectly.

Second phase is to add my library which uses spring as well. After adding all the needed dependencies in the `build.gradle` i've managed to compile it.

Now I have 2 jars in the `build\lib` folder. The plain one - which is only my classes like before. And the big one which includes all my dependencies - spring boot, my test library and more...

When I copy this big jar to jmeter I'm getting this error [image: big jar]

Is there a way to include my dependencies and still make it work in Jmeter ?

Comment: Why do you need Spring Boot for a JMeter sampler? What does it do, send HTTP requests?

Comment: Our service is based on Java and spring boot. Then we developed an client simulator (GUI) + test core module (mqtt base) which is developed also in spring boot - so we can use it also in our integration tests and also as a simple client simulator. And now I would like to reuse this test core module in jmeter sampler. If i won't find a solution my plan is to breat the test core module into 2 modules.. 1 spring boot base and one pure java. But this will make me few hours of work at least that I try to prevent.

Comment: You can use non-Spring classes in both JMeter and your tests if you know how to turn those in beans during testing.

Comment: Yes I guess I will do that.. Hours of research or hours of transferring my code to non-spring boot classes would be still hours of work :)

Answer (score 1):

You created yourself a [Jar Hell](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-jar-hell), remove the "plain" jar and leave only the "fat" one.

In general I don't think you can run a Spring Boot application inside JMeter context, when it comes to multithreading the second thread will fail.

I think the better option would be going the other way, include JMeter into the Spring Boot application, it can be done:

- Either by calling the relevant JMeter API functions directly (no limitations but coding might be a little bit tricky, see [JMeter Command Line Overview: 5 Ways To Launch a Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-command-line) for more details)
- Or you can use [JMeter Java DSL](https://abstracta.github.io/jmeter-java-dsl/) (more convenient but doesn't support 100% of JMeter features)

Comment: Thanks for this direction.. But unfortunately using the other way of using JMeter is less an option for us, because we use AWS services, and we might want to use in the future [AWS load testing](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/distributed-load-testing-on-aws) which I've saw that can load jmeter samplers.